# Materialize Match Card Height with Footer

Tags: jquery, css, materialize

I've tried to use Flexbox and [Match Height](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height), but no matter what I do it does not want to fix everything the right way. If you take a look at [vijeos.com](http://vijeos.com) you'll see some cards that have longer titles do not work properly. I need the title to be the correct height with the Category, Comment, and Share fixed to the bottom of the page. Can't figure out what I am doing wrong?

Before Match Height
[image]

[After Match Height](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height)
[image]

As you can see it fixes the height issue, but Category: is still all over the place. Any help would be amazing :)

Script:

```
    //Dynamic Card Titles
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".card-content").matchHeight();
    });
```

Current Code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col xl4 l4 m12 s12">
    <div class="card z-depth-5">
      <div class="card-image">
        <a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1742/naked-girl-ordering-pizza-prank' title='Naked Girl Ordering Pizza Prank'><img class="responsive-img" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/_SYuFDQREgM/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Naked Girl Ordering Pizza Prank Image"></a>
        <span class="card-title"></span>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SYuFDQREgM" class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light black" title="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SYuFDQREgM" rel="nofollow"><i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p><a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1742/naked-girl-ordering-pizza-prank' rel='nofollow' title='Naked Girl Ordering Pizza Prank Video'>Naked Girl Ordering Pizza Prank</a></p>
        <br />
        <p style="text-align:left;">Category: <a href='http://vijeos.com/category/pranks/page/1' rel='nofollow'>Pranks</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col xl4 l4 m12 s12">
    <div class="card z-depth-5">
      <div class="card-image">
        <a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1741/breakfast-candh' title='Breakfast C&H'><img class="responsive-img" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/ULMXplGmleQ/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Breakfast C&H Image"></a>
        <span class="card-title"></span>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULMXplGmleQ" class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light black" title="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULMXplGmleQ" rel="nofollow"><i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p><a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1741/breakfast-candh' rel='nofollow' title='Breakfast C&H Video'>Breakfast C&H</a></p>
        <br />
        <p style="text-align:left;">Category: <a href='http://vijeos.com/category/weird/page/1' rel='nofollow'>Weird</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col xl4 l4 m12 s12">
    <div class="card z-depth-5">
      <div class="card-image">
        <a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1740/riding-motorcycles-alone-can-have-its-pitfalls' title='Riding Motorcycles Alone Can Have It"s Pitfalls...'><img class="responsive-img" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/FCpvmfhVyco/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Riding Motorcycles Alone Can Have It's Pitfalls... Image "></a>
        <span class="card-title "></span>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCpvmfhVyco " class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light black " title="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCpvmfhVyco " rel="nofollow "><i class="material-icons ">play_arrow</i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content ">
        <p>
          <a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1740/riding-motorcycles-alone-can-have-its-pitfalls' rel='nofollow' title='Riding Motorcycles Alone Can Have It' s Pitfalls... Video '>Riding Motorcycles Alone Can Have It's Pitfalls...</a></p>
        <br />
        <p style="text-align:left; ">Category: <a href='http://vijeos.com/category/fails/page/1' rel='nofollow'>Fails</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col xl4 l4 m12 s12 ">
    <div class="card z-depth-5 ">
      <div class="card-image ">
        <a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1739/rollerblading-down-a-bobsled-track' title='Rollerblading Down a Bobsled Track'><img class="responsive-img " src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/SymoRr3tbG8/mqdefault.jpg " alt="Rollerblading Down a Bobsled
          Track Image "></a>
        <span class="card-title "></span>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SymoRr3tbG8 " class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light black " title="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SymoRr3tbG8 " rel="nofollow "><i class="material-icons ">play_arrow</i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content ">
        <p><a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1739/rollerblading-down-a-bobsled-track' rel='nofollow' title='Rollerblading Down a Bobsled Track Video'>Rollerblading Down a Bobsled Track</a></p>
        <br />
        <p style="text-align:left; ">Category: <a href='http://vijeos.com/category/wins/page/1' rel='nofollow'>Wins</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col xl4 l4 m12 s12 ">
    <div class="card z-depth-5 ">
      <div class="card-image ">
        <a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1738/almost-wins' title='Almost Wins'><img class="responsive-img " src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/3XPmG6EktNY/mqdefault.jpg " alt="Almost Wins Image "></a>
        <span class="card-title "></span>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XPmG6EktNY " class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light black " title="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XPmG6EktNY " rel="nofollow "><i class="material-icons ">play_arrow</i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content ">
        <p><a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1738/almost-wins' rel='nofollow' title='Almost Wins Video'>Almost Wins</a></p>
        <br />
        <p style="text-align:left; ">Category: <a href='http://vijeos.com/category/fails/page/1' rel='nofollow'>Fails</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col xl4 l4 m12 s12 ">
    <div class="card z-depth-5 ">
      <div class="card-image ">
        <a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1737/birdie-gets-his-nails-trimmed' title='Birdie Gets His Nails Trimmed'><img class="responsive-img " src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/_6zzskV6p80/mqdefault.jpg " alt="Birdie Gets His Nails Trimmed Image "></a>
        <span class="card-title "></span>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6zzskV6p80 " class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light black " title="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6zzskV6p80 " rel="nofollow "><i class="material-icons ">play_arrow</i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content ">
        <p><a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1737/birdie-gets-his-nails-trimmed' rel='nofollow' title='Birdie Gets His Nails Trimmed Video'>Birdie Gets His Nails Trimmed</a></p>
        <br />
        <p style="text-align:left; ">Category: <a href='http://vijeos.com/category/animals/page/1' rel='nofollow'>Animals</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col xl4 l4 m12 s12 ">
    <div class="card z-depth-5 ">
      <div class="card-image ">
        <a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1736/bear-and-cubs-swim-in-backyard-pool' title='Bear and Cubs Swim in Backyard Pool'><img class="responsive-img " src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/tdW7qpAno9s/mqdefault.jpg " alt="Bear and Cubs Swim in Backyard
          Pool Image "></a>
        <span class="card-title "></span>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdW7qpAno9s " class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light black " title="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdW7qpAno9s " rel="nofollow "><i class="material-icons ">play_arrow</i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content ">
        <p><a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1736/bear-and-cubs-swim-in-backyard-pool' rel='nofollow' title='Bear and Cubs Swim in Backyard Pool Video'>Bear and Cubs Swim in Backyard Pool</a></p>
        <br />
        <p style="text-align:left; ">Category: <a href='http://vijeos.com/category/animals/page/1' rel='nofollow'>Animals</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col xl4 l4 m12 s12 ">
    <div class="card z-depth-5 ">
      <div class="card-image ">
        <a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1735/speedo-man' title='Speedo Man'><img class="responsive-img " src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/UjosUah2F3A/mqdefault.jpg " alt="Speedo Man Image "></a>
        <span class="card-title "></span>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjosUah2F3A " class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light black " title="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjosUah2F3A " rel="nofollow "><i class="material-icons ">play_arrow</i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content ">
        <p><a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1735/speedo-man' rel='nofollow' title='Speedo Man Video'>Speedo Man</a></p>
        <br />
        <p style="text-align:left; ">Category: <a href='http://vijeos.com/category/fails/page/1' rel='nofollow'>Fails</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col xl4 l4 m12 s12 ">
    <div class="card z-depth-5 ">
      <div class="card-image ">
        <a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1734/whats-inside-a-bladeless-fan' title='What' s inside a Bladeless Fan? '><img class="responsive-img " src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/2Wnep79ULAI/mqdefault.jpg " alt="What 's inside a Bladeless Fan? Image "></a>
              <span class="card-title "></span>
              <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Wnep79ULAI " class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light black " title="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Wnep79ULAI " rel="nofollow "><i class="material-icons ">play_arrow</i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content ">
              <p><a href='http://vijeos.com/post/1734/whats-inside-a-bladeless-fan ' rel='nofollow ' title='What 's inside a Bladeless Fan? Video'>What's inside a Bladeless Fan?</a>
        </p>
        <br />
        <p style="text-align:left; ">Category: <a href='http://vijeos.com/category/tech/page/1' rel='nofollow'>Tech</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

would the card medium and large classes work for you use case? If you needed larger than those provide you could change one of the classes and supply your own max height